# iOS 5.0 SDK - USB host OTG

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, usb, mfi

I would like to connect to the iPhone a device that was **not** manufactured specifically for the iPhone. It can be accessed from a PC through USB, so what I'd like to do is connect it through an iPhone dock connector-USB adaptor. I am aware of the previous questions regarding this topic but most of them seem outdated.

1. Can it be done in the newest iOS SDK (5.0 or higher)? (If no, can I dit it with a jailbroken iPhone?)
2. Are there any limitations?
3. Do I have to join the MFI program? AFAIK, MFI program is aimed at companies that are creating hardware components **together** with the software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do it with a jailbroken phone.

Otherwise you would have to join the MFI, and it would additionally require custom hardware on the device.

Comment: Will it work with any jailbroken iPhone (like the classic, or 1st gen 3G), or was USB Host only added in recent models?